# External authentication module prevent further authentication

Tags: 7, forms, users

I am trying to make an external authentication module for Drupal, and I have one almost done, except that after I successfully authenticate the user (or throw an error), Drupal's standard authentication kicks in and adds error messages to the form error stack.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
/**
* Implements hook_form_alter().
* We replace the local login validation handler with our own.
*/
function XXXX_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Add our validation function to the form
  if ($form_id == 'user_login' || $form_id == 'user_login_block') {
    $form['#validate'][] = 'XXXX_authenticate';
  }
}

/**
* Custom user authentication function
*/
function XXXX_authenticate($form, &$form_state) {

  $name = $form_state['values']['name'];

  if(XXXX_is_valid_user()) {
    user_external_login_register($name, 'XXXX');
    return true;
  } else {
    // in the full module, this would be set in another function.
    form_set_error('user', t('The XXXXXX error'));
  }
}

function XXXX_is_valid_user() {
  // return false;
  return true;
}
```

This is for demonstration purposes, only. It is trying to log the user in no matter what the user types (because the actual module is too complicated to put in its' entirety).

The problem is that user_external_login_register works correctly, except that If XXXX_is_valid_user() returns false, the standard invalid login error appears before the actual error, and if the login succeeds, the standard invalid login error appears on a page where the user is logged in.

I have tried form_clear_error, but either it's not clearing the error properly, or an additional authentication is being added after this form submits. I think this module would work correctly if there was a way to either prevent further authentication, or replace the authentication code currently in place with this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the default login function, in a hook_form_alter. You're trying to append to $validators, below I'm overriding it with:

```
$validator = 'dew_auth_id_authenticate_validate';
```

So my example code is:

```
/**
 * This function alters the default login form we are presenting to the student.
 *
 * It overrides the typical drupal login authentication scheme and injects our
 * own localized version.
 */
function _dew_auth_user_login_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  global $conf;
  $saveForm = $form;
  $form = array();

  $status_type = is_esci_open_for_submissions() ? 'availability_message_open' : 'availability_message_closed';
  $form['availability_message'] = array(
    '#markup' => _dew_auth_availability_message_html($status_type, TRUE),
    '#weight' => -10,
  );

  # overrides the default validator.
  foreach ($saveForm as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == '#validate') {
      $form[$key] = array();
      foreach ($value as $validator) {
        if ($validator == 'user_login_authenticate_validate') {
          // If we progressed down to this level of nested Alters, we have
          // #auth-destination. #auth-destination is a key I add to the $form
          // to know which login mechanism I want to call and use. The site
          // has 3 login mechanisms.
          $type_of_login = $saveForm['#auth-destination'];
          switch($type_of_login) {
            case 'id':
              $validator = 'dew_auth_id_authenticate_validate';
              $form['#action'] = '/?q=id/login&destination=%3Cfront%3E';
              break;
            case ESCI_ENDUSER_TYPE:
              $validator = 'dew_identity_service_authenticate_validate';
              break;
            default:
              break;
          }
        }
        $form[$key][] = $validator;
      }
    }
    else {
      $form[$key] = $value;
    }
  }
  $form['name']['#title'] = ($type_of_login == 'id') ? 'Department Username' : 'CAMPUS ID';

  if ($type_of_login == ESCI_ENDUSER_TYPE) {
    $form['links']['#markup'] = '<div><a target="_blank" href="https://secure.network-diagnostics.edu/netid_diags/">Unable to Login? Verify your Campus Access Credentials</a></div>';
    $form['links']['#weight'] = 199;
  // For Departmental logins just hide the default drupal links to reset passwords.
  } else {
    unset($form['links']);
  }
}
```

Then functions like `dew_identity_service_authenticate_validate` and `dew_auth_id_authenticate_validate` are just copy/paste "clones" of user_login_authenticate_validate from drupal core with some 3-5 extra lines of custom logic -- they also in turn use custom copy/pasted drupal core `*_user_external_login_register` functions to properly create users depending on the method the user was created on the website.

Note this level of customization is good for say Drupal 7. But will have to be re-created if you move to Drupal 8.

Comment: I tried it, but for some reason the login dies on the next page refresh, now. I tried a different approach before and ran into the same problem. Either the default authentication exists and I get both a login and a login error, or I log the user in via user_external_login_register and the user loses login on the next page load.

Comment: And I was able to fix that by adding the following code after my user_external_login_register function:
global $user;
$form_state['uid'] = $user->uid;

Comment: ya thats why I said you copy/paste the user_login_authenitcate_validate functions and their php body into your own function -- when you do external authentication you must assure you keep the same default Drupal login procedures in place ... if you neglect to add that `$uid` value upon success ... drupal never knows you've logged in and everything blows up. I didnt show you my function for that because it's kinda big and custom for my needs.